# Recommended Distributed Cache size for WFE + DC minrole

Tags: 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, distributedcache, minrole

What formula do you use for allocating memory to a WFE with Distributed Cache?

MS recommends half of 10% which is too small:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/manage-the-distributed-cache-service

Spencer recommends half of 80% which seems way to much for the only WFE server in my environment, given that DC can use up to 80% of total RAM when set to 40% cache size:
http://www.harbar.net/archive/2016/04/15/SharePoint-2016-Nugget-2-Distributed-Cache-Size-in-MinRole-Farms.aspx

Comment: How much memory you have on your servers? what is expected load on the server?

Comment: Memory on WFE with DC is 16GB and has three web applications (Intranet and docs, extranet, and my sites).  We have dedicated servers for other service applications, central admin and search.  Total number of users is around 2000 but concurrent users is closer to 100 or less

Comment: how many WFE you have? does Search run on different server then other service applications?

Comment: Only one WFE server.  Distributed cache only runs on the WFE.  There is a dedicated search server for all search components.  There is an APP server that runs all other service apps like UPS.

Answer (score 3):

But you are here describing two different set of Distributed Cache.
First is about using DC on WFE server, the second is about to have server with MinRole - DistributedCache, where you are using more % of RAM.

When you are using DC on SP WFE servers, we are using 10% of total RAM, but sizing of WFE servers depends on howm any web applications, how many users will be connecting, so for classic company **there are 22GB or more of RAM. so DC using 2GB at least. This is role WFE with Distributed Cache.**

If you create dedicated **server with MinRole DistributedCache** you can use more % of RAM, here I recommend the set, which you provide here, **so 40% of total RAM, so for 22GB RAM it is 8GB.**

*You must have in mind that sizing of servers and applications depends on lots of variables like users, applications, where is crawl online, etc...*

Comment: Thanks for confirming the 40% option is for Minrole: DC only, and not for WFE.  I'd still like to know if we should increase DC size from 10% on a WFE.

Comment: Sometimes we are using 20% on WFE, it depends on how free ram there are, its caused by amount of people who are facing web applications, number of webapplications, if there is available crawl and lots of other things... In high usage of RAM you need to have about 10% free all the time for good response of SharePoint. You must do a decide.

Answer (score 2):

it is kind of tricky, You have to check performance of your farm before going up or down. 10% of total memory is not bad in 16GB server. With the MinRole, it is easy to manage it as less services / unwanted service on the server...Because SharePoint automatically shutdown non-compliant services.

I would also enable the DC on the Server to make it High Available type of cluster (I know its not truly HA). If you enable it on APP and WFE then you will have two server with 1.6GB each which make 3.2GB total. i think this is enough for you.

Read the changing size section of this article. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/manage-the-distributed-cache-service